# How to manage two or more consumers via pthreads?

Tags: c, multithreading, io, pthreads, buffer

I have a generic problem I am looking to solve, where chunks of binary data sent from a standard input or regular file stream to an application, which in turn converts that binary data into text. Using threads, I want to process the text before piping it over to the next application, which modifies that text even further, and so on.

As a simple test case, I want to extract compressed data via `gunzip`. Specifically, I am looking at using `gunzip -c -` to extract chunks of binary data sent to it via its (reassigned) `stdin` file descriptor, and then pulling out chunks of text from its (reassigned) `stdout` file descriptor. I can then print these chunks of text to the real `stdout` or `stderr` (or do other stuff, later on).

(I realize that I can do `gzip`-based compression and extraction on the command line. My goal here is to use this test case to learn how to correctly pass around generic chunks of binary and text data between threads that either run that data through binaries, or process it further.)

In the case of my test program, I have set up three `pthread_t` threads:

- `produce_gzip_chunk_thread`
- `consume_gzip_chunk_thread`
- `consume_gunzip_chunk_thread`

I pass each of these threads a shared data instance called `thread_data`, which contains a thread lock, two conditions, and some buffers and counter variables. I also include a set of file descriptors for a `gunzip` process opened with `popen3()`:

```
typedef struct pthread_data pthread_data_t;
typedef struct popen3_desc popen3_desc_t;

struct pthread_data {
    pthread_mutex_t in_lock;
    pthread_cond_t in_cond;
    pthread_cond_t out_cond;
    unsigned char in_buf[BUF_LENGTH_VALUE];
    size_t n_in_bytes;
    size_t n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip;
    size_t n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip;
    FILE *in_file_ptr;
    boolean in_eof;
    char in_line[LINE_LENGTH_VALUE];
    popen3_desc_t *gunzip_ptr;
};

struct popen3_desc {
    int in;
    int out;
    int err;
};
```

The `produce_gzip_chunk_thread` reads in a 1024-byte chunk of `gzip`-compressed bytes from a regular file called `foo.gz`.

These bytes are written to an `unsigned char` buffer called `in_buf`, which is part of the shared data struct I am passing to each thread:

```
void * produce_gzip_chunk(void *t_data)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> produce_gzip_chunk()\n");
#endif

    pthread_data_t *d = (pthread_data_t *)t_data;
    unsigned char in_buf[BUF_LENGTH_VALUE];
    size_t n_in_bytes = 0;

    d->in_eof = kFalse;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&d->in_lock);
    while(kTrue) {
        n_in_bytes = fread(in_buf, sizeof(in_buf[0]), sizeof(in_buf), d->in_file_ptr);
        if (n_in_bytes > 0) {
            while (d->n_in_bytes != 0 || d->n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip != 0)
                pthread_cond_wait(&d->in_cond, &d->in_lock);
            memcpy(d->in_buf, in_buf, n_in_bytes);
            d->n_in_bytes = n_in_bytes;
#ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: ######## [%07zu] produced chunk\n", d->n_in_bytes);
#endif
            pthread_cond_signal(&d->in_cond);
        }
        else if (feof(d->in_file_ptr) || ferror(d->in_file_ptr))
            break;
    } 
    d->in_eof = kTrue;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->in_lock);
    pthread_cond_signal(&d->in_cond);

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> produce_gzip_chunk()\n");
#endif
    return NULL;
}
```

Once there is a positive number of bytes stored in `n_bytes` — that is, we have pulled data from our input `gzip` archive that needs to be processed with `gunzip` — this triggers a condition that permits the second thread `consume_gzip_chunk_thread` to operate:

```
void * consume_gzip_chunk(void *t_data)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> consume_gzip_chunk()\n");
#endif

    pthread_data_t *d = (pthread_data_t *)t_data;
    long n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&d->in_lock);
    while(kTrue) {
        while (d->n_in_bytes == 0 && !d->in_eof)
            pthread_cond_wait(&d->in_cond, &d->in_lock);
        if (d->n_in_bytes) {
#ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: ........ [%07zu] processing chunk\n", d->n_in_bytes);
#endif
            if (!d->gunzip_ptr) {
#ifdef DEBUG
                fprintf(stderr, "Debug: * setting up gunzip ptr\n");
#endif
                d->gunzip_ptr = malloc(sizeof(popen3_desc_t));
                if (!d->gunzip_ptr) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not create gunzip file handle struct\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                popen3("gunzip -c -", 
                       &(d->gunzip_ptr->in), 
                       &(d->gunzip_ptr->out), 
                       &(d->gunzip_ptr->err), 
                       kTrue, 
                       kTrue);
                memset(d->in_line, 0, LINE_LENGTH_VALUE);
            }
            n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip = (long) write(d->gunzip_ptr->in, d->in_buf, d->n_in_bytes);
#ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: ................ wrote [%07ld] bytes into the gunzip process\n", n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip);
#endif
            if (n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip > 0)
                d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip = n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip;

            d->n_in_bytes = 0;
            pthread_cond_signal(&d->out_cond);
        }
        if (d->in_eof) 
            break;
    } 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->in_lock);

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> consume_gzip_chunk()\n");
#endif
    return NULL;
}
```

When consuming the `gzip` data chunk, we use the `write` function to send `n_bytes` of `in_buf` to the `gunzip` process's input file descriptor. At the end, we send another thread signal, but this time to `out_cond`, so as to help reawaken `consume_gunzip_chunk_thread`, which reads from `gunzip`'s output to do more work:

```
void * consume_gunzip_chunk(void *t_data)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> consume_gunzip_chunk()\n");
#endif

    pthread_data_t *d = (pthread_data_t *)t_data;
    long n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&d->in_lock);
    while(kTrue) {
        while (d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip == 0) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&d->out_cond, &d->in_lock);
        }
        if (d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip) {
            sleep(1);
            n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip = read(d->gunzip_ptr->out, d->in_line, LINE_LENGTH_VALUE);
#ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: ------------------------ read [%07ld] bytes out from the gunzip process\n", n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip);
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: ------------------------ gunzip output chunk:\n[%s]\n", d->in_line);
#endif
            memset(d->in_line, 0, strlen(d->in_line));
            if (n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip > 0)
                d->n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip = n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip;
            d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip = 0;
            pthread_cond_signal(&d->in_cond);
        }
        if (d->in_eof && (d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip == 0))
            break;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->in_lock);

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> consume_gunzip_chunk()\n");
#endif
    return NULL;
}
```

This attempts to `read` any available bytes from the `gunzip` process's output file descriptor. For debugging purposes, I just want to print them to `stderr` for now.

The problem I am facing is that I need to add a `sleep(1)` statement in `consume_gunzip_chunk`, before doing the `read`, in order to get things working properly.

Without this `sleep(1)` statement, my test program will usually output nothing — except once every 8-10 attempts, when the compressed data are extracted correctly.

**Question** - What am I doing wrong about my arrangement of conditions, such that the `sleep(1)` call is required to make the `gzip`-extraction work properly? In a production scenario, working with much larger input files, forcibly waiting a second every 1kB seems like a bad idea.

---

For reproducibility with the full source code, here are the two relevant files. Here is the header:

```
/*
 * convert.h
 */

#ifndef CONVERT_H
#define CONVERT_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define CB_VERSION "1.0"
#define LINE_LENGTH_VALUE 65536
#define BUF_LENGTH_VALUE 1024
#define POPEN3_READ 0
#define POPEN3_WRITE 1

typedef int boolean;
extern const boolean kTrue;
extern const boolean kFalse;
const boolean kTrue = 1;
const boolean kFalse = 0;

typedef enum {
    kGzip,
    kUnknown
} format_t;

typedef struct pthread_data pthread_data_t;
typedef struct popen3_desc popen3_desc_t;

struct pthread_data {
    pthread_mutex_t in_lock;
    pthread_cond_t in_cond;
    pthread_cond_t out_cond;
    unsigned char in_buf[BUF_LENGTH_VALUE];
    size_t n_in_bytes;
    size_t n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip;
    size_t n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip;
    boolean in_eof;
    FILE *in_file_ptr;
    popen3_desc_t *gunzip_ptr;
    char in_line[LINE_LENGTH_VALUE];
};

struct popen3_desc {
    int in;
    int out;
    int err;
};

static const char *name = "convert";
static const char *version = CB_VERSION;
static const char *authors = "Alex Reynolds";
static const char *usage = "\n" \
    "Usage: convert --input-format=str <input-file>\n" \
    "  Process Flags:\n\n" \
    "  --input-format=str            | -f str  Input format (str = [ gzip ]; required)\n" \
    "  --help                        | -h      Show this usage message\n";

static struct convert_globals_t {
    char *input_format_str;
    format_t input_format;
    char **filenames;
    int num_filenames;
} convert_globals;

static struct option convert_client_long_options[] = {
    { "input-format",           required_argument,  NULL,   'f' },
    { "help",               no_argument,        NULL,   'h' },
    { NULL,             no_argument,        NULL,    0  }
}; 

static const char *convert_client_opt_string = "f:h?";

void * consume_gunzip_chunk        (void *t_data);
void * consume_gzip_chunk          (void *t_data);
void * produce_gzip_chunk          (void *t_data);
FILE * new_file_ptr                (const char *in_fn);
void   delete_file_ptr             (FILE **file_ptr);
pid_t  popen3                      (const char *command, 
                                    int *in_desc, 
                                    int *out_desc, 
                                    int *err_desc, 
                                    boolean nonblock_in, 
                                    boolean nonblock_outerr);
off_t  fsize                       (const char *fn);
void   initialize_globals          ();
void   parse_command_line_options  (int argc, 
                                    char **argv);
void   print_usage                 (FILE *stream);

#endif
```

Here is the implementation:

```
/*
 * convert.c
 */

#include "convert.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> main()\n");
#endif

    pthread_t produce_gzip_chunk_thread = NULL;
    pthread_t consume_gzip_chunk_thread = NULL;
    pthread_t consume_gunzip_chunk_thread = NULL;
    pthread_data_t *thread_data = NULL;

    parse_command_line_options(argc, argv);

    /* initialize thread data */
    thread_data = malloc(sizeof(pthread_data_t));
    thread_data->n_in_bytes = 0;
    thread_data->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip = 0;
    thread_data->n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip = 0;
    thread_data->in_eof = kFalse;
    thread_data->in_file_ptr = new_file_ptr(convert_globals.filenames[0]);
    pthread_mutex_init(&(thread_data->in_lock), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(thread_data->in_cond), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(thread_data->out_cond), NULL);

    /* parse input */
    if (convert_globals.input_format == kGzip) 
        {
            if (pthread_create(&produce_gzip_chunk_thread, NULL, produce_gzip_chunk, (void *) thread_data) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not create gzip chunk production thread\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if (pthread_create(&consume_gzip_chunk_thread, NULL, consume_gzip_chunk, (void *) thread_data) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not create gzip chunk consumption thread\n");            
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if (pthread_create(&consume_gunzip_chunk_thread, NULL, consume_gunzip_chunk, (void *) thread_data) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not create gunzip chunk consumption thread\n");            
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if (pthread_join(produce_gzip_chunk_thread, NULL) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not join gzip chunk production thread\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if (pthread_join(consume_gzip_chunk_thread, NULL) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not join gzip chunk consumption thread\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if (pthread_join(consume_gunzip_chunk_thread, NULL) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not join gunzip chunk consumption thread\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    else
        {
            /* 
               handle text formats
            */
        }

    /* cleanup */
    delete_file_ptr(&thread_data->in_file_ptr);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&(thread_data->in_lock));
    pthread_cond_destroy(&(thread_data->in_cond));
    pthread_cond_destroy(&(thread_data->out_cond));
    free(thread_data);

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> main()\n");
#endif
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void * consume_gunzip_chunk(void *t_data)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> consume_gunzip_chunk()\n");
#endif

    pthread_data_t *d = (pthread_data_t *)t_data;
    long n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&d->in_lock);
    while(kTrue) {
        while (d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip == 0) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&d->out_cond, &d->in_lock);
        }
        if (d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip) {
            sleep(1);
            n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip = read(d->gunzip_ptr->out, d->in_line, LINE_LENGTH_VALUE);
#ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: ------------------------ read [%07ld] bytes out from the gunzip process\n", n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip);
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: ------------------------ gunzip output chunk:\n[%s]\n", d->in_line);
#endif
            memset(d->in_line, 0, strlen(d->in_line));
            if (n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip > 0)
                d->n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip = n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip;
            d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip = 0;
            pthread_cond_signal(&d->in_cond);
        }
        if (d->in_eof && (d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip == 0))
            break;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->in_lock);

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> consume_gunzip_chunk()\n");
#endif
    return NULL;
}

void * consume_gzip_chunk(void *t_data)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> consume_gzip_chunk()\n");
#endif

    pthread_data_t *d = (pthread_data_t *)t_data;
    long n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&d->in_lock);
    while(kTrue) {
        while (d->n_in_bytes == 0 && !d->in_eof)
            pthread_cond_wait(&d->in_cond, &d->in_lock);
        if (d->n_in_bytes) {
#ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: ........ [%07zu] processing chunk\n", d->n_in_bytes);
#endif
            if (!d->gunzip_ptr) {
#ifdef DEBUG
                fprintf(stderr, "Debug: * setting up gunzip ptr\n");
#endif
                d->gunzip_ptr = malloc(sizeof(popen3_desc_t));
                if (!d->gunzip_ptr) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not create gunzip file handle struct\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                popen3("gunzip -c -", 
                       &(d->gunzip_ptr->in), 
                       &(d->gunzip_ptr->out), 
                       &(d->gunzip_ptr->err), 
                       kTrue, 
                       kTrue);
                memset(d->in_line, 0, LINE_LENGTH_VALUE);
            }
            n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip = (long) write(d->gunzip_ptr->in, d->in_buf, d->n_in_bytes);
#ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: ................ wrote [%07ld] bytes into the gunzip process\n", n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip);
#endif
            if (n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip > 0)
                d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip = n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip;

            d->n_in_bytes = 0;
            /* pthread_cond_signal(&d->in_cond); */
            pthread_cond_signal(&d->out_cond);
        }
        if (d->in_eof) 
            break;
    } 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->in_lock);

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> consume_gzip_chunk()\n");
#endif
    return NULL;
}

void * produce_gzip_chunk(void *t_data)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> produce_gzip_chunk()\n");
#endif

    pthread_data_t *d = (pthread_data_t *)t_data;
    unsigned char in_buf[BUF_LENGTH_VALUE];
    size_t n_in_bytes = 0;

    d->in_eof = kFalse;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&d->in_lock);
    while(kTrue) {
        n_in_bytes = fread(in_buf, sizeof(in_buf[0]), sizeof(in_buf), d->in_file_ptr);
        if (n_in_bytes > 0) {
            while (d->n_in_bytes != 0 || d->n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip != 0)
                pthread_cond_wait(&d->in_cond, &d->in_lock);
            memcpy(d->in_buf, in_buf, n_in_bytes);
            d->n_in_bytes = n_in_bytes;
#ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: ######## [%07zu] produced chunk\n", d->n_in_bytes);
#endif
            pthread_cond_signal(&d->in_cond);
        }
        else if (feof(d->in_file_ptr) || ferror(d->in_file_ptr))
            break;
    } 
    d->in_eof = kTrue;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&d->in_lock);
    pthread_cond_signal(&d->in_cond);

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> produce_gzip_chunk()\n");
#endif
    return NULL;
}

FILE * new_file_ptr(const char *in_fn)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> new_file_ptr()\n");
#endif

    FILE *file_ptr = NULL;
    boolean not_stdin = kTrue;

    not_stdin = strcmp(in_fn, "-");
    file_ptr = (not_stdin) ? fopen(in_fn, "r") : stdin;

    if (!file_ptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open input stream\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> new_file_ptr()\n");
#endif
    return file_ptr;
}

void delete_file_ptr(FILE **file_ptr)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> delete_file_ptr()\n");
#endif

    fclose(*file_ptr);
    *file_ptr = NULL;

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> delete_file_ptr()\n");
#endif
}

pid_t popen3(const char *command, int *in_desc, int *out_desc, int *err_desc, boolean nonblock_in, boolean nonblock_outerr)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> popen3()\n");
#endif

    int p_stdin[2], p_stdout[2], p_stderr[2];
    pid_t pid;

    if (pipe(p_stdin) != 0 || pipe(p_stdout) != 0 || pipe(p_stderr) != 0)
        return -1;

    if (nonblock_in) {
        fcntl(p_stdin[POPEN3_WRITE], F_SETFL, fcntl(p_stdin[POPEN3_WRITE], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
    }

    if (nonblock_outerr) {
        fcntl(p_stdout[POPEN3_READ], F_SETFL, fcntl(p_stdout[POPEN3_READ], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
        fcntl(p_stderr[POPEN3_READ], F_SETFL, fcntl(p_stderr[POPEN3_READ], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        return pid; /* error */

    if (pid == 0) {
        close(p_stdin[POPEN3_WRITE]);
        close(p_stdout[POPEN3_READ]);
        close(p_stderr[POPEN3_READ]);
        dup2(p_stdin[POPEN3_READ], fileno(stdin));
        dup2(p_stdout[POPEN3_WRITE], fileno(stderr));
        dup2(p_stdout[POPEN3_WRITE], fileno(stdout));
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not execl [%s]\n", command);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (in_desc == NULL)
        close(p_stdin[POPEN3_WRITE]);
    else
        *in_desc = p_stdin[POPEN3_WRITE];

    if (out_desc == NULL)
        close(p_stdout[POPEN3_READ]);
    else
        *out_desc = p_stdout[POPEN3_READ];

    if (err_desc == NULL)
        close(p_stderr[POPEN3_READ]);
    else
        *err_desc = p_stderr[POPEN3_READ];

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: New *in_desc  = %d\n", *in_desc);
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: New *out_desc = %d\n", *out_desc);
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: New *err_desc = %d\n", *err_desc);
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> popen3()\n");
#endif
    return pid;
}

off_t fsize(const char *fn) 
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> fsize()\n");
#endif

    struct stat st; 

    if (stat(fn, &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> fsize()\n");
#endif
    return EXIT_FAILURE; 
}

void initialize_globals()
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> initialize_globals()\n");
#endif

    convert_globals.input_format = kUnknown;
    convert_globals.filenames = NULL;
    convert_globals.num_filenames = 0;

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> initialize_globals()\n");
#endif
}

void parse_command_line_options(int argc, char **argv)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> parse_command_line_options()\n");
#endif

    int client_long_index;
    int client_opt = getopt_long(argc, 
                                 argv, 
                                 convert_client_opt_string, 
                                 convert_client_long_options, 
                                 &client_long_index);
    char *in_format_str = NULL;

    opterr = 0; /* disable error reporting by GNU getopt */
    initialize_globals();

    while (client_opt != -1) 
        {
            switch (client_opt) 
                {
                case 'f':
                    in_format_str = optarg;
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    print_usage(stdout);
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                case '?':
                    print_usage(stdout);
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                default:
                    break;
                }
            client_opt = getopt_long(argc, 
                                     argv, 
                                     convert_client_opt_string, 
                                     convert_client_long_options, 
                                     &client_long_index);
        }

    convert_globals.filenames = argv + optind;
    convert_globals.num_filenames = argc - optind;    

    if (!in_format_str) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Specified input format was omitted; please specify one of required input formats\n");
        print_usage(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (convert_globals.num_filenames != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Please specify an input file (either a regular file or '-' for stdin\n");
        print_usage(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* map format string to setting */
    if (strcmp(in_format_str, "gzip") == 0)
        convert_globals.input_format = kGzip;
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Specified input format is unknown; please specify one of required input formats\n");
        print_usage(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> parse_command_line_options()\n");
#endif
}

void print_usage(FILE *stream)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Entering --> print_usage()\n");
#endif

    fprintf(stream, 
            "%s\n" \
            "  version: %s\n" \
            "  author:  %s\n" \
            "%s\n", 
            name, 
            version,
            authors,
            usage);

#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "Debug: Leaving  --> print_usage()\n");
#endif
}
```

Here is the build process:

```
$ mkdir -p objects
$ cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DDEBUG=1 -g -O0 -fno-inline -c convert.c -o objects/convert.o -iquote${PWD}                                                        
$ cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DDEBUG=1 -g -O0 -fno-inline objects/convert.o -o convert -lpthread
```

I have been able to build this test code on OS X and Linux hosts with reasonably modern compile environments.

Thanks in advance for any useful advice!

Comment: Just to clarify. _Must we_ use your data structures and locking schemes? Because my intention is to _greatly_ simplify this pipeline, in particular by not using condition variables and mutexes, unless you can provide me with a good reason why you must use them.

Comment: You don't have to use my code. I'm providing it to show what work I have done, and to give a compilable, reproducible work that displays the problem. If you can solve the problem while making sure that each step doesn't happen out-of-order, i.e. overwrite data, then I'd love to see that, too. The key is that I am able to step in between producer and consumer steps with my own functions, which will modify the data state. Does that help?

Comment: But surely that does not require `pthread_cond_t`? Can you not simply use pipes, the output of a process being written to the write-end and the thread reading from the read-end? And is there any particular reason for non-blocking fds?

Comment: I have tried a non-mutex, non-signal version, but the program locks up at processing the first chunk of buffered data. I am using threads to process a chunk of data, in order, with processes and my own functions. I am using non-blocking file descriptors to keep the program from hanging. If blocking flags are left in place, the program hangs.

Comment: The conditions are there so that threads process chunks in order. Otherwise, I get a situation where a thread sits forever, waiting for input, which is why that variant of code hangs.

Comment: Aside from my work below (which I would love if you could critique the completeness thereof), can you elaborate on "process chunks in order"? To the best of my knowledge, in a pipeline it's impossible not to do so... Did I miss something in your specifications?

Comment: I have a collection of threads that produce and consume data, which I need to coordinate. If they are uncoordinated, then some downstream data could be processed (and, say, sent to `stdout`) before some upstream data comes in. This could result in data loss or corruption.

Comment: Oh... In other words you want all data to run through one binary and be buffered at output. Then you want all that buffered output to be fed as input to the next binary only once the previous binary completed its work. Is this correct? Or is this buffering done at the level of a line? Because if it is done at the level of a line, how do you know a priori how much of `gunzip`'s output to read to prevent corruption?

Comment: I want to read a chunk of (say, uncompressed) data into buffer. I want to process that buffer one line at a time, and feed that into another buffer. I want to write the contents of the new buffer to another binary. And so on. Basically, I want to recapitulate a shell script that uses pipes, except that I want to do this in C, and I want to control the order in which work is done. So long as I read and write from and to buffers in order, and so long as the binaries are working correctly, and so long as I can prevent processes from hanging, I don't think I should expect data corruption.

Comment: Think I may have found your problem (It's in my answer in a new section at the bottom) but unfortunately I can't reproduce your failure mode (even with the unmodified source code) on Mac OS X 10.6. Do tell if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot as soon as I can review it.

Answer (score 7):

I will start by saying that I feel pthreads conditions and mutexes were not really necessary here, nor was non-blocking I/O the best reaction to the problems you describe.

In my opinion, the problems you describe with your condition- and mutex-less version are symptoms of forgetting to `close()` assiduously the ends of your pipes, with the result that a copy of the writing-end file descriptor of the pipe feeding the child process's `stdin` leaked (into that child or others) alive.

Then, given that a writing-end corresponding to stdin's reading-end still existed, the system did not give EOF but instead blocked indefinitely.

In your case, you *did* prevent the pipe-end file descriptors from leaking to the spawned child (with the correct `close()` calls on the child-side of the `fork()` within your `popen3()`, although you forgot to `close()` the wrong-end pipe ends on the parent-side). However, you did not prevent this leakage to *all other children*! If you call `popen3()` twice, the leakage of the set of three descriptors into the child is prevented, but as the parent still owns them, when the next call to `popen3()` happens, after the `fork()` there are now **6** file descriptors to close (The old set of three and and the new set of three you just created).

In your case, therefore, you should set the close-on-exec flag on those pipe ends, thusly:

```
fcntl(fdIn [PIPEWR], F_SETFD, fcntl(fdIn [PIPEWR], F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC);
fcntl(fdOut[PIPERD], F_SETFD, fcntl(fdOut[PIPERD], F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC);
fcntl(fdErr[PIPERD], F_SETFD, fcntl(fdErr[PIPERD], F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC);
```

Here is code that spawns 6 threads and 3 processes, and passes its input unmodified to the output, after internally compressing then decompressing it. It effectively implements `gzip -c - | XOR 0x55 | XOR 0x55 | gunzip -c - | cat`, where:

1. Standard input is fed to to `gzip` by thread `srcThrd`.
2. `gzip`'s output is read by thread `a2xor0Thrd` and fed to thread `xor0Thrd`.
3. Thread `xor0Thrd` XORs its input with `0x55` before passing it on to thread `xor1Thrd`.
4. Thread `xor1Thrd` XORs its input with `0x55` before passing it on to thread `xor22BThrd`.
5. Thread `xor22BThrd` feeds its input to process `gunzip`.
6. Process `gunzip` feeds its output directly (without going through a thread) to `cat`
7. Process `cat`'s output is read by thread `dstThrd` and printed to standard output.

Compression is done by inter-process pipe communication, while XORing is done by intra-process pipe communication. No mutexes or condition variables are used. `main()` is extremely easy to understand. This code should be easy to extend to your situation.

```
/* Includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



/* Defines */
#define PIPERD 0
#define PIPEWR 1




/* Data structures */
typedef struct PIPESET{
    int Ain[2];
    int Aout[2];
    int Aerr[2];
    int xor0[2];
    int xor1[2];
    int xor2[2];
    int Bin[2];
    int BoutCin[2];
    int Berr[2];
    int Cout[2];
    int Cerr[2];
} PIPESET;




/* Function Implementations */

/**
 * Source thread main method.
 * 
 * Slurps from standard input and feeds process A.
 */

void* srcThrdMain(void* arg){
    PIPESET* pipeset = (PIPESET*)arg;

    char c;
    while(read(0, &c, 1) > 0){
        write(pipeset->Ain[PIPEWR], &c, 1);
    }

    close(pipeset->Ain[PIPEWR]);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * A to XOR0 thread main method.
 * 
 * Manually pipes from standard output of process A to input of thread XOR0.
 */

void* a2xor0ThrdMain(void* arg){
    PIPESET* pipeset = (PIPESET*)arg;

    char    buf[65536];
    ssize_t bytesRead;

    while((bytesRead = read(pipeset->Aout[PIPERD], buf, 65536)) > 0){
        write(pipeset->xor0[PIPEWR], buf, bytesRead);
    }

    close(pipeset->xor0[PIPEWR]);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * XOR0 thread main method.
 * 
 * XORs input with 0x55 and outputs to input of XOR1.
 */

void* xor0ThrdMain(void* arg){
    PIPESET* pipeset = (PIPESET*)arg;

    char c;
    while(read(pipeset->xor0[PIPERD], &c, 1) > 0){
        c ^= 0x55;
        write(pipeset->xor1[PIPEWR], &c, 1);
    }

    close(pipeset->xor1[PIPEWR]);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * XOR1 thread main method.
 * 
 * XORs input with 0x55 and outputs to input of process B.
 */

void* xor1ThrdMain(void* arg){
    PIPESET* pipeset = (PIPESET*)arg;

    char c;
    while(read(pipeset->xor1[PIPERD], &c, 1) > 0){
        c ^= 0x55;
        write(pipeset->xor2[PIPEWR], &c, 1);
    }

    close(pipeset->xor2[PIPEWR]);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * XOR2 to B thread main method.
 * 
 * Manually pipes from input (output of XOR1) to input of process B.
 */

void* xor22BThrdMain(void* arg){
    PIPESET* pipeset = (PIPESET*)arg;

    char    buf[65536];
    ssize_t bytesRead;

    while((bytesRead = read(pipeset->xor2[PIPERD], buf, 65536)) > 0){
        write(pipeset->Bin[PIPEWR], buf, bytesRead);
    }

    close(pipeset->Bin[PIPEWR]);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * Destination thread main method.
 * 
 * Manually copies the standard output of process C to the standard output.
 */

void* dstThrdMain(void* arg){
    PIPESET* pipeset = (PIPESET*)arg;

    char c;
    while(read(pipeset->Cout[PIPERD], &c, 1) > 0){
        write(1, &c, 1);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * Set close on exec flag on given descriptor.
 */

void setCloExecFlag(int fd){
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC);
}

/**
 * Set close on exec flag on given descriptor.
 */

void unsetCloExecFlag(int fd){
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) & ~FD_CLOEXEC);
}

/**
 * Pipe4.
 * 
 * Create a pipe with some ends possibly marked close-on-exec.
 */

#define PIPE4_FLAG_NONE       (0U)
#define PIPE4_FLAG_RD_CLOEXEC (1U << 0)
#define PIPE4_FLAG_WR_CLOEXEC (1U << 1)

int pipe4(int fd[2], int flags){
    int ret = pipe(fd);

    if(flags&PIPE4_FLAG_RD_CLOEXEC){setCloExecFlag(fd[PIPERD]);}
    if(flags&PIPE4_FLAG_WR_CLOEXEC){setCloExecFlag(fd[PIPEWR]);}

    return ret;
}

/**
 * Pipe4 explicit derivatives.
 */

#define pipe4_cloexec(fd)  pipe4((fd), PIPE4_FLAG_RD_CLOEXEC|PIPE4_FLAG_WR_CLOEXEC)

/**
 * Popen4.
 * 
 * General-case for spawning a process and tethering it with cloexec pipes on stdin,
 * stdout and stderr.
 * 
 * @param [in]      cmd    The command to execute.
 * @param [in/out]  pin    The pointer to the cloexec pipe for stdin.
 * @param [in/out]  pout   The pointer to the cloexec pipe for stdout.
 * @param [in/out]  perr   The pointer to the cloexec pipe for stderr.
 * @param [in]      flags  A bitwise OR of flags to this function. Available
 *                         flags are:
 * 
 *     POPEN4_FLAG_NONE:
 *         Explicitly specify no flags.
 *     POPEN4_FLAG_NOCLOSE_PARENT_STDIN,
 *     POPEN4_FLAG_NOCLOSE_PARENT_STDOUT,
 *     POPEN4_FLAG_NOCLOSE_PARENT_STDERR:
 *         Don't close pin[PIPERD], pout[PIPEWR] and perr[PIPEWR] in the parent,
 *         respectively.
 *     POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDIN,
 *     POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDOUT,
 *     POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDERR:
 *         Close the respective streams in the child. Ignores pin, pout and perr
 *         entirely. Overrides a NOCLOSE_PARENT flag for the same stream.
 */

#define POPEN4_FLAG_NONE                             (0U)
#define POPEN4_FLAG_NOCLOSE_PARENT_STDIN        (1U << 0)
#define POPEN4_FLAG_NOCLOSE_PARENT_STDOUT       (1U << 1)
#define POPEN4_FLAG_NOCLOSE_PARENT_STDERR       (1U << 2)
#define POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDIN           (1U << 3)
#define POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDOUT          (1U << 4)
#define POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDERR          (1U << 5)

pid_t popen4(const char* cmd, int pin[2], int pout[2], int perr[2], int flags){
    /********************
     **  FORK PROCESS  **
     ********************/
    pid_t ret = fork();

    if(ret < 0){
        /**
         * Error in fork(), still in parent.
         */

        fprintf(stderr, "fork() failed!\n");
        return ret;
    }else if(ret == 0){
        /**
         * Child-side of fork
         */

        if(flags & POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDIN){
            close(0);
        }else{
            unsetCloExecFlag(pin [PIPERD]);
            dup2(pin [PIPERD], 0);
        }
        if(flags & POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDOUT){
            close(1);
        }else{
            unsetCloExecFlag(pout[PIPEWR]);
            dup2(pout[PIPEWR], 1);
        }
        if(flags & POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDERR){
            close(2);
        }else{
            unsetCloExecFlag(perr[PIPEWR]);
            dup2(perr[PIPEWR], 2);
        }

        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmd, NULL);

        fprintf(stderr, "exec() failed!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }else{
        /**
         * Parent-side of fork
         */

        if(~flags & POPEN4_FLAG_NOCLOSE_PARENT_STDIN  &&
           ~flags & POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDIN){
            close(pin [PIPERD]);
        }
        if(~flags & POPEN4_FLAG_NOCLOSE_PARENT_STDOUT &&
           ~flags & POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDOUT){
            close(pout[PIPEWR]);
        }
        if(~flags & POPEN4_FLAG_NOCLOSE_PARENT_STDERR &&
           ~flags & POPEN4_FLAG_CLOSE_CHILD_STDERR){
            close(perr[PIPEWR]);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /* Unreachable */
    return ret;
}

/**
 * Main Function.
 * 
 * Sets up the whole piping scheme.
 */

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    pthread_t srcThrd, a2xor0Thrd, xor0Thrd, xor1Thrd, xor22BThrd, dstThrd;
    pid_t     gzip, gunzip, cat;
    PIPESET   pipeset;

    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.Ain);
    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.Aout);
    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.Aerr);
    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.Bin);
    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.BoutCin);
    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.Berr);
    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.Cout);
    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.Cerr);
    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.xor0);
    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.xor1);
    pipe4_cloexec(pipeset.xor2);

    /* Spawn processes */
    gzip   = popen4("gzip -c -",   pipeset.Ain,     pipeset.Aout,    pipeset.Aerr, POPEN4_FLAG_NONE);
    gunzip = popen4("gunzip -c -", pipeset.Bin,     pipeset.BoutCin, pipeset.Berr, POPEN4_FLAG_NONE);
    cat    = popen4("cat",         pipeset.BoutCin, pipeset.Cout,    pipeset.Cerr, POPEN4_FLAG_NONE);


    /* Spawn threads */
    pthread_create(&srcThrd,    NULL, srcThrdMain,    &pipeset);
    pthread_create(&a2xor0Thrd, NULL, a2xor0ThrdMain, &pipeset);
    pthread_create(&xor0Thrd,   NULL, xor0ThrdMain,   &pipeset);
    pthread_create(&xor1Thrd,   NULL, xor1ThrdMain,   &pipeset);
    pthread_create(&xor22BThrd, NULL, xor22BThrdMain, &pipeset);
    pthread_create(&dstThrd,    NULL, dstThrdMain,    &pipeset);
    pthread_join(srcThrd,    (void**)NULL);
    pthread_join(a2xor0Thrd, (void**)NULL);
    pthread_join(xor0Thrd,   (void**)NULL);
    pthread_join(xor1Thrd,   (void**)NULL);
    pthread_join(xor22BThrd, (void**)NULL);
    pthread_join(dstThrd,    (void**)NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

### Commentary on your own code

There are many issues with your code, most of which have nothing to do with threading.

- You don't `close()` the file descriptor `d->gunzip_ptr->in`. This means that `gunzip` can never know that no more input is forthcoming on its `stdin`, so it will never exit.
- Since `gunzip` doesn't ever exit, it will never `close()` its stdout, and thus a blocking `read()` at the other end will never unblock. A non-blocking read will instead always give `-1`, with `errno == EAGAIN`.
- Your `popen3()` doesn't `close()` `p_stdin[POPEN3_READ]`, `p_stdout[POPEN3_WRITE]` or `p_stderr[POPEN3_WRITE]` on the parent side of the `fork()`. Only the child should have those descriptors. Failing to close these means that when the parent itself tries to read the stdout and stderr of the child, it will never see EOF, again for the same reasons as above: Because it itself still owns a write-end pipe in which it could write, making new data appear to the read-end.
- Your code implicitly relies on `gunzip` writing out at least one byte for every 1024 you write in. There is no guarantee that this will be the case, since `gunzip` may, at its leisure, buffer internally.

  - This is because your code reads then copies chunks of at most `BUF_LENGTH_VALUE` bytes into `d->in_buf`. You then assign the number of bytes you read through `fread()` to `d->n_in_bytes`. This same `d->n_in_bytes` is used in your `write()` call to write to `gunzip`'s stdin. You then signal for `consume_gunzip_chunk()` to wake up, then `pthread_cond_wait()`'s for the next gzip-compressed chunk. But this gzip-compressed chunk may never come, since there is no guarantee that `gunzip` will be able to unpack useful output from just the first 1024 bytes of input, nor even a guarantee that it will `write()` it out instead of buffering it until it has, say, 4096 bytes (a full page) of output. Therefore, the `read()` call in `consume_gunzip_chunk()` may never succeed (or even return, if `read()` was blocking). And if `read()` never returns, then `consume_gunzip_chunk()` doesn't signal `d->in_cond`, and so all three threads get stuck. And even if `read()` is non-blocking, the last block of output from gzip may never come, since `gzip`'s input is never closed, so it doesn't flush out its buffers by `write()`'ing them out, so `read()` on the other end will never get useful data and no amount of pleading will elicit it without a `close()`.
- **POSSIBLE (LIKELY?) CAUSE OF BUG**: `d->n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip`, once it becomes non-`0`, will never become `0` again. This means that the extremely baffling

  ```
  while (d->n_in_bytes != 0 || d->n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip != 0)
      pthread_cond_wait(&d->in_cond, &d->in_lock);
  ```

  within `produce_gzip_chunk()` will, once entered with `d->n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip != 0`, forever remain stuck. By calling `sleep(1)` within `consume_gunzip_chunk()`, which sets `d->n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip`, you may have defused the problem by reading all input before `consume_gunzip_chunk()` could lock up the system by setting `d->n_out_bytes_read_from_gunzip` to a non-zero value.
- There are *two* threads that call `pthread_cond_wait(&d->in_cond, &d->in_lock);`, these being `produce_gzip_chunk()` and `consume_gzip_chunk()`. There is absolutely no guarantee that when `consume_gunzip_chunk()` calls `pthread_cond_signal(&d->in_cond);`, that the "correct" thread (whichever it is in your design) will receive the signal. To ensure that all of them will, use `pthread_cond_broadcast()`, but then you expose yourself to the [thundering herd problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem). Needing to use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` in this situation is, again, a symptom of a bad design in my opinion.
- Related, you call `pthread_cond_signal(&d->in_cond)` within a thread (indeed, a *function*) in which you call `pthread_cond_wait(&d->in_cond, &d->in_lock)`. What purpose does that serve?
- You use `d->in_lock` for too many disparate purposes, exposing yourself to the possibility of deadlock, or low performance due to excessive protection. In particular you use it as the protection for both `d->in_cond` and `d->out_cond`. This is too strong a protection – the output of `gunzip` into `d->in_line` should be able to happen simultaneously with the input of `gunzip` being written into and out of `d->in_buf`.
- Within `consume_gunzip_chunk()`, you have

  ```
  while (d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip == 0) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&d->out_cond, &d->in_lock);
  }
  if (d->n_in_bytes_written_to_gunzip) {
      ...
  ```

  This `if` can never fail! Is there a case you may have in mind?
- Consider making the entire `struct pthread_data` volatile (or at least those integer elements which are used by multiple threads), since the compiler might decide to optimize out loads and stores that should, in fact, remain.

### Compliments

So as to not sound too negative, I would like to say that in general your problems were not due to misuse of the pthreads API but due to erroneous consumer-producer logic and lack of `close()`s. Additionally, you appear to understand that `pthread_cond_wait()` may wake up [spuriously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup), and so you have wrapped it up in a loop that checks the invariant.

### In the future:

I would use pipes, even between threads. This absolves you from needing to implement your own consumer-producer scheme; The kernel has solved it for you already, and provides you with the `pipe()`, `read()` and `write()` primitives, which are all you need to take advantage of this ready-made solution. It also makes the code cleaner and void of mutexes and condition variables. One must simply be diligent in closing the ends, and one must be supremely careful around pipes in the presence of `fork()`. The rules are simple:

- If a pipe's write-end exists, a `read()` on an open read-end will not give EOF but will block or `EAGAIN`.
- If a pipe's write-ends have all been closed, a `read()` on an open read-end will give EOF.
- If a pipe's read-ends have all been closed, a `write()` to any of its write-ends will cause `SIGPIPE`.
- `fork()` duplicates the entire process, including **all** descriptors (modulo maybe crazy stuff in `pthread_atfork()`)!

Comment: I was kind of hoping for an answer that deals with threads and conditions so that I can learn what I'm doing wrong with my code. I don't know why threads and conditions are not appropriate here. But I will review this and see if this works. If it works, I'd like to try to add a thread/function that processes output from `gunzip` on a per-line basis, and another thread that processes that output on a per-token basis (say, word by word). If that works, then I'll give you the points.

Comment: @AlexReynolds I've added a thorough critique of your code, that you may learn something from your work.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Found a bug in `popen3()`, also added to the list.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Updated my code. I wrote my own `pipe4` and `popen4`, which together should be a joy for you to use, as can be seen in my new `main()`. Should be scalable to a quasi-arbitrary number of binaries and threads in the pipeline. You just have to do smarter buffering than I did in my code above. If you want to wire two processes together directly without intervening threads, `popen4` has flags that should allow you to do that too.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Never mind that, `popen4` already had all the power it needed to do direct process-to-process. Read above for changes to my code.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Have you gotten around to reviewing before-before-yesterday's new code and the commentary immediately below it? Is there anything more I should add to the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Ah.  So I think I misunderstood the question....  sorry.

I had thought you wanted to run gunzip and then one other internal filter, and wanted to do that 'N' times.

It seems what you really want to do is run many stages of filters, one after the other... some using external commands and some (perhaps ?) internal to the program.  Hence the desire to manage some inter-stage buffering.

So... I've had another go at this.  The objective is to run any number of stages, starting with the input stage, then extrenal command or internal function "filter" stages, and finally the output stage.  Each external command stage had three pthreads -- for stdin, stdout and stderr.  Internal function stages use one pthread and the initial input and final output one pthread each.  Between the stages is a small pipe structure (called a "straw") to "double buffer" and decouple the stages... I hope this is closer to what you had in mind.

The "straw" is the essence of the thing:

```
struct straw
{
  pthread_mutex_t*  mutex ;

  struct lump*  free ;
  pthread_cond_t* free_cond ;
  bool          free_waiting ;

  struct lump*  ready ;
  pthread_cond_t* ready_cond ;
  bool          ready_waiting ;

  struct lump*  lumps[2] ;
} ;
```

where a `struct lump` contains a buffer and what-not.  The "straw" has two such "lumps", and at any moment one pthread may be filling one lump, while another is draining the other.  Or both lumps may be free (on the free list) or both ready (full) waiting on the ready list.

Then to aquire an empty lump to fill it (eg when reading from a pipe):

```
static struct lump*
lump_acquire(struct straw* strw)
{
  struct lump* lmp ;

  pthread_mutex_lock(strw->mutex) ;

  while (strw->free == NULL)
    {
      strw->free_waiting = true ;
      pthread_cond_wait(strw->free_cond, strw->mutex) ;
      strw->free_waiting = false ;
    } ;

  lmp = strw->free ;
  strw->free = lmp->next ;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(strw->mutex) ;

  lmp->next = NULL ;                    /* tidy                 */

  lmp->ptr  = lmp->end = lmp->buff ;    /* empty                */
  lmp->done = false ;

  return lmp ;
} ;
```

Then to blow the completed lump into (one end of) the straw.

```
static void
lump_blow(struct lump* lmp)
{
  struct straw* strw ;

  strw = lmp->strw ;

  qassert((lmp == strw->lumps[0]) || (lmp == strw->lumps[1])) ;
  qassert( (lmp->buff <= lmp->ptr)
                     && (lmp->ptr <= lmp->end)
                                 && (lmp->end <= lmp->limit) ) ;

  lmp->ptr = lmp->buff ;

  pthread_mutex_lock(strw->mutex) ;

  if (strw->ready == NULL)
    strw->ready = lmp ;
  else
    strw->ready->next = lmp ;
  lmp->next = NULL ;

  if (strw->ready_waiting)
    pthread_cond_signal(strw->ready_cond) ;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(strw->mutex) ;
} ;
```

To suck a lump out of (the other end of) the straw:

```
static struct lump*
lump_suck(struct straw* strw)
{
  struct lump* lmp ;

  pthread_mutex_lock(strw->mutex) ;

  while (strw->ready == NULL)
    {
      strw->ready_waiting = true ;
      pthread_cond_wait(strw->ready_cond, strw->mutex) ;
      strw->ready_waiting = false ;
    } ;

  lmp = strw->ready ;
  strw->ready = lmp->next ;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(strw->mutex) ;

  qassert( (lmp->buff <= lmp->ptr)
                     && (lmp->ptr <= lmp->end)
                                 && (lmp->end <= lmp->limit) ) ;

  lmp->ptr = lmp->buff ;        /* lmp->ptr..lmp->end   */
  lmp->next = NULL ;            /* tidy                 */

  return lmp ;
} ;
```

And the final piece, freeing a lump once it has been drained:

```
static void
lump_free(struct lump* lmp)
{
  struct straw* strw ;

  strw = lmp->strw ;

  qassert((lmp == strw->lumps[0]) || (lmp == strw->lumps[1])) ;
  qassert( (lmp->buff <= lmp->ptr)
                     && (lmp->ptr <= lmp->end)
                                 && (lmp->end <= lmp->limit) ) ;

  pthread_mutex_lock(strw->mutex) ;

  if (strw->free == NULL)
    strw->free = lmp ;
  else
    strw->free->next = lmp ;

  lmp->next = NULL ;                    /* end of list of free  */

  lmp->ptr  = lmp->end = lmp->buff ;    /* empty                */
  lmp->done = false ;

  if (strw->free_waiting)
    pthread_cond_signal(strw->free_cond) ;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(strw->mutex) ;
} ;
```

The entire program is too big to fit in an answer -- see: [pipework.c](http://www.halldom.com/stackoverflow/pipework.c) where that starts:

```
/*==============================================================================
 * pipework.c
 *
 * Copyright (c) Chris Hall (GMCH) 2014, All rights reserved.
 *
 * Though you may do what you like with this, provided you recognise that
 * it is offered "as is", gratis, and may or may not be fit for any purpose
 * whatsoever -- you are on your own.
 *
 *------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This will read from stdin, pass the data through an arbitrary number of
 * "filter" stages and finally write the result to stdout.
 *
 * A filter stage may be an external command taking a piped stdin and
 * outputting to a piped stdout.  Anything it says to stderr is collected
 * and output to the program's stderr.
 *
 * A filter stage may also be an internal function.
 *
 * The input, filter and output stages are implemented as a number of pthreads,
 * with internal, miniature pipes (called "straws") between them.  All I/O is
 * blocking.  This is an experiment in the use of pthreads to simplify things.
 *
 * ============================
 * This is v0.08 of  4-Jul-2014
 * ============================
 *
 * The 'main' below runs eight stages: input, 4 commands, 2 internal filters
 * and the output.  The output should be an exact copy of the input.
 *
 * In order to test the stderr handling, the following small perl script is
 * used as two of the command filters:
 *
 *   chatter.pl
 *   --------------------------------------------------------
     use strict ;
     use warnings ;

     my $line = 0 ;
     while (<STDIN>)
       {
         my $len = length($_) ;
         my $r   = rand ;

         $line += 1 ;
         print STDERR "|$line:$len:$r|" ;

         if (int($r * 100) == 0)
           {
             print STDERR "\n" ;
           } ;

         print $_ ;
       } ;
 *   --------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Limitations
 *
 *   * this will crash if it gets some error its not expecting or not
 *     designed to overcome.  Clearly, to be useful this needs to be more
 *     robust and more informative.
 *
 *   * some (possible/theoretical) errors are simply ignored.
 *
 *   * no attempt is made to collect up the child processes or to discover
 *     their return codes.  If the child process reports errors or anything
 *     else on stderr, then that will be visible.  But otherwise, if it just
 *     crashes then the pipeline will run to completion, but the result may
 *     be nonsense.
 *
 *   * if one of the child processes stalls, the whole thing stalls.
 *
 *   * an I/O error in a stage will send 'end' downstream, but the program
 *     will continue until everything upstream has completed.
 *
 *   * generally... not intended for production use !!
 */
```

And the perl script is available as: [chatter.pl](http://www.halldom.com/stackoverflow/chatter.pl)

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the part 'How to manage two or more consumers via pthreads?' of your post let me cite these points about ['Designing Threaded Programs'](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Designing):

> In general though, in order for a program to take advantage of
>   Pthreads, it must be able to be organized into discrete, independent
>   tasks which can execute concurrently. For example, if routine1 and
>   routine2 can be interchanged, interleaved and/or overlapped in real
>   time, they are candidates for threading.

and

> Several common models for threaded programs exist:
>
> - Manager/worker: a single thread, the manager assigns work to other    threads, the workers. Typically, the manager handles all input and
>     parcels out work to the other tasks. At least two forms of the
>     manager/worker model are common: static worker pool and dynamic
>     worker pool.
> - Pipeline: a task is broken into a series of suboperations, each of    which is handled in series, but concurrently, by a different thread.
>     An automobile assembly line best describes this model.
> - Peer: similar to the manager/worker model, but after the main thread    creates other threads, it participates in the work.

Regarding your problem...

> The problem I am facing is that I need to add a sleep(1) statement in
>   consume_gunzip_chunk, before doing the read, in order to get things
>   working properly.

[Eric Lippert](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/4318/eric-lippert) [Best Practices with Multithreading in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55335) might not solve it but, they should help you finding the right solution to your multi-threaded program, particularly points 5, and 8:

> 5.At all costs avoid shared memory. Most threading bugs are caused by a failure to understand real-world shared memory semantics. If you
>   must make threads, treat them as though they were processes: give them
>   everything they need to do their work and let them work without
>   modifying the memory associated with any other thread. Just like a
>   process doesn't get to modify the memory of any other process.
>
> 8.If you use Thread.Sleep with an argument other than zero or one in any production code, you are possibly doing something wrong. Threads
>   are expensive; you don't pay a worker to sleep, so don't pay a thread
>   to sleep either. If you are using sleeps to solve a correctness issue
>   by avoiding a timing problem -- as you appear to be in your code --
>   then you definitely have done something deeply wrong. Multithreaded
>   code needs to be correct irrespective of accidents of timing.

Comment: +1, Thanks for making this advice explicit. Locks and conditions should be used in such a way as to guarantee that the execution flow is always funneled correctly at your synchronization points, no matter how perverse or outright hostile the relative timing of the threads is. In particular, assume your code runs under an EvilOS which ensures that all of your `sleep()`'s are compensated for in other threads.