# When piping, why do you have to close() the opposite end of a pipe before using dup2()?

Tags: c, pipe

In this code example, I noticed that you have to close the opposite end of a piped read buffer before writing to it, and vice versa. Why is that and what kind of consequences or side effects would there be if you didn't close the opposite end?

```
int main() {
  char b[20];
  int p[2];
  int rc = pipe( p );
  int pid = fork();

  if ( pid > 0 ) {
    close( p[0] );
    rc = dup2( p[1], 1 );
  }

  printf( "0987654321" );
  fflush( NULL );

  if ( pid == 0 ) {
    close( p[1] );
    rc = read( p[0], b, 6 );
    b[rc] = '\0';
    printf( "%d-%s\n", getpid(), b );
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The relative ordering of `close(p[0])` and `dup2(p[1], 1)` doesn't matter, but it _is_ important to `close()` the "wrong" ends in each process. If this is not done, at best you'll leak file descriptors, preventing the processes from opening as many files as it previously could; At worst you'll cause a hang, because a `read()` won't return EOF if it's waiting on a pipe read-end for which some write-ends haven't been `close()`'d. So when you `fork()`, be especially dilligent in closing the write-ends of all pipes that aren't meant to be used by that forked process.

Comment: The close and dup2 calls have nothing to do with each other, except that they both work with the pipe.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427599) of a case where a devious leak in pipeline ends led to a race condition and hang. My solution to that question involved the _close-on-exec_ flag, which auto-closes file descriptors on `exec()`; But you don't have that luxury since you're not exec'ing any process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to close the opposite ends so that only one of your forked processes tries to read data from the pipe. For symmetry, it's a good idea to close the input side of your pipe.

The other reason for doing this is defensive programming. Eventually, you must close the pipe, or you'll be leaking file handles. If you don't need them, close them right away so you don't forget to do it later.

Comment: You also usually want `EPIPE`/`SIGPIPE` when the reader closes its end. If you still have an open copy of the reading fd, that will never happen.